# How to add coded value to domain?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, domains

I wish to add a new value in my domain and I get this message :

An invalid SQL statement was used [UPDATE GDB_Domains SET DomainName = 'Statut_Pygargue',Description = Statut de l'activite du nid', MergePolicy = 3, SplitPolicy = 3 WHEREID = 20]

I am the owner of the file geodatabase.

Comment: Would you be able to list the steps you used to try and add a new value to your domain, please?  You can do this using the edit button to update your question.

Comment: I think you have a syntax error or two. First the Description field is missing the starting quote and then, since you're using single quotes, the apostrophe in the value causes a premature end.